# Plotly table subplot disable dragging columns

Tags: plotly, plotly-python

I have 2 plotly subplots, a surface plot and table plot. By default table plots have columns which you can drag and move, I want to disable this feature, I have found the command

```
config = {'staticPlot': True} 
fig.show(config=config)
```

works but this also affects the surface plot which doesn't display properly. how do I set this config only on the table subplot?
Also is there a way the table can behave like regular html text where i can select and copy values? Right now it is like an image i cannot select a cell. Thank you

```
fig = make_subplots(
rows=2, cols=1,
row_heights=[0.9, 0.5],
vertical_spacing=0.03,
specs=[[{"type": "surface"}],
       [{"type": "table"}]])


fig_table = go.Table(
    header=dict(
        values=[""] + desired_x_axis,
        font=dict(size=12),
        align="left"
    ),
    cells=dict(
        font=dict(size=11),
        values=z_values,
        align = "left",
        fill=dict(color=['#ced9e4','#F0F8FF']))
    
        
)

config = {'staticPlot': True} 
fig.show(config=config)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking for a Plotly funcionality to easily disable this drag-and-drop behavior for a while and I did not found anything. One simply way to achieve it -only for the first table, extendible for others- is to add this JavaScript line to the code (I use the argument `include_plotlyjs` of the function `fig.to_html()`, but there should be other ways):

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("table")[0].style.pointerEvents = "none";
```

With this is not needed to include `{'staticPlot': True}`.